Disable SonarJava Check
I am using code climate in my code, to check the code quality.
This is my .codeclimate.yml:
version: '2'
plugins:
  sonar-java:
    enabled: true
    config:
      minimum_severity: critical
checks:
  S1192:
    enabled: false
exclude_patterns: []

I was getting a lot of "Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal" warning so I wanted to suppress it, and hence I used the code S1192. Event after adding this, the check is not suppressed.
I tried disabling that check, but that did not happen.

If you're not using Sonar and want to disable it from your Code Climate configuration, you can simply remove or comment out the sonar-java plugin section in your .codeclimate.yml file. Here's how you can adjust your configuration:
Updated .codeclimate.yml
version: '2'
plugins:
sonar-java:
enabled: true
config:
minimum_severity: critical
checks:
S1192:
enabled: false
exclude_patterns: []

Hi, thanks for the response, I am using sonar java as my code quality analyser, there are other checks too ( i did not add them here) and I do not wish to disable it. I just wish to suppress
"Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal"
warning. Any help there would be appreciated.

Yes, you can easily disable them; it depends on which IDE you are using. If you are using STS, just follow these steps, and you can turn off whichever ones you want.  Navigate to Window > Preferences, then search for SonarLint. Go to Rules Configuration, select Java, and disable any rules you wish to turn off.
